# Creating sheets using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I want to dynamically create a Google Spreadsheet using the Sheets API with a Service account and JWT in Cloud Function.
The sheet is inaccessible by others except for the Service Email (which I cannot Login with).

Is there a workaround?

```
const SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"];

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT({
  email: serviceAccount.client_email,
  key: serviceAccount.private_key,
  scopes: SCOPES
});

const jwtAuthPromise = jwtClient.authorize();
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4" });

exports.createNewSS = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const resource = {
    properties: {
      title: "Testing sheet " + Date.now()
    }
  };
  await jwtAuthPromise;
  await sheets.spreadsheets.create(
    {
      auth: jwtClient,
      fields: "spreadsheetId",
      resource
    },
    (err, ss) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log("Error creating new sheet: " + err);
      }
      res.send(ss.data);
      return console.log(ss.data);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: To further make it accessible, I gave the Service account access to a drive folder and moved the Sheet into it. And even changed the Owner of the Sheet using the Drive API.